# android how can i create a sliding layout as used in a Music player

Tags: android

I am trying to do a Music player. Like in some Music player when a song is playing if u touch the screen progress Seekbar will come and after touch_up, after some time that seekbar will automatically slide down. If u again touch the screen it again come back like slide up.

I don't know whether that is a slider or different.
How can i do that in my application. Is there any way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  [Sliding Drawer](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-sliding-drawer/), [Sliding Drawer in android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)  and control it on the touch

Comment: I want from buttom to upwards. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is with Orientation as Horizontal or Vertical.. there r many examples available ..

Comment: Will u give me some examples?

Comment: The link that i have provided in  my answer include this..Go through it

Comment: ya that for left right, i asked for buttom to up. where i ll change?

Comment: Go through the sliding Drawer in developer.android.com and go through its property.. set the layout of sliding drawer at bottom position and use animateToClose() and animateToOpen() methods to slide it